# Adding an Operator to the Context Menu of a UIList

Tags: python, scripting, interface

How may I add an operator to the Context Menu of a UI List?
[image: Context Menu of UI List]

Context menus seem to be defined per Spaces (e.g. `NODE_MT_context_menu` in the below code). Could this be set for the menu of a region? Thank you!

```py
def draw_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator("node.duplicate_move", text="My new context menu item")

def register():
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.append(draw_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.remove(draw_menu)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a UI list context menu you can use `bpy.types.UI_MT_list_item_context_menu`. So in your code snippet:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.UI_MT_list_item_context_menu.append(draw_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.UI_MT_list_item_context_menu.remove(draw_menu)
```

To figure out the type, I executed this in the Python console and looked for the most plausible one:

```
blender_types = dir(bpy.types)
for blender_type in blender_types:
    if 'context_menu' in blender_type:
        print(blender_type)
```

**In addition:**

What type of list and which list item did the user right-click on? [According to the Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html#extending-the-button-context-menu) you can use `context.button_pointer` and `context.button_prop` for that. See the code example in the docs for a dump function of all the properties of `button_pointer` and `button_prop`.

As far as I can tell, `context.button_pointer.active` is the list item the user clicked on.

`context.button_prop.name` gives an indication which type of list is clicked, e.g. 'Active Shape Key Index' or 'Active Vertex Group Index'. This name is used as title at the top of the context menu:

[image]

Comment: That's waaaaay cleaner than my previous solution! Thank you so much Sietse!!!

Comment: Oh, one question: how do I know which UI list is right-clicked (when there are many) from that draw menu function?

Comment: Yeah, good question. `context.button_pointer.active` points at the active item in the list. I will update my answer.

Comment: As an addition not all data containers implement an `active` member, so the second method might fail. You can get the active item with `getattr(context.button_pointer, context.button_prop.identifier)`