# How to document two or more different operator's options with Online Manual?

Tags: python, operator

It's not clear to me whether or not it's possible to document 2 different options of the same operator, so by right clicking on the operator's buttons it's possible to go to the documentation. The problem is if the operator has 2 or more options, it might do slightly different things. I wanted to be able to document them.

[image]

I modified the "Addon Add Object" template to make the example.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import EnumProperty

class MYADDON_OT_Operator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.operator"
    bl_label = "Custom ops"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    options: EnumProperty(default='ONE', items = (('ONE', "One", ""), ('TWO', "Two", "")))


    def execute(self, context):
                
        # Two different situation:
        
        if self.options == 'ONE':  # Doc This
            print("One")
        elif self.options == 'TWO': # Doc This
            print("Two")
            
        # How to make 2 different url with same operator?

        return {'FINISHED'}



# This allows you to right click on a button and link to documentation
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.myaddon.operator", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
    )    
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYADDON_OT_Operator)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MYADDON_OT_Operator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible. Also it wouldn't make any sense to have more than one option for showing a manual because everything in your addon would be documented in that one manual link. Consider using tooltips for different buttons.

Comment: The use of tooltips is certainly useful, in fact I always use them according to the chosen option of the trade, usually it's a piece of cake. I'm facing the online documentation problem for the first time. Usually I used links with an operator well positioned in the panel, with an icon (?) but this time I wanted to deal with the documentation issue in a more "Professional" way, right click and go 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_object_manual_map` returns a url string at runtime so we can tap into the logic there. Unfortunately we don't have access to the context in this function so it may not work in a remote setting. But we can use `bpy.context` and make use of the barely documented [bpy.context.button_operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html#extending-the-button-context-menu).

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import EnumProperty


class MYADDON_OT_operator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.operator"
    bl_label = "Custom ops"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    options: EnumProperty(default='ONE', items = (('ONE', "One", ""), ('TWO', "Two", "")))

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}


# This allows you to right click on a button and link to documentation
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    
    operator = getattr(bpy.context, "button_operator", None)
    
    option = operator.options if type(operator).__name__ == "MYADDON_OT_operator" else "ONE"

    if option == "ONE":
        url_manual_mapping = (
            ("bpy.ops.myaddon.operator", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        )
    elif option == "TWO":
        url_manual_mapping = (
            ("bpy.ops.myaddon.operator", "scene_layout/object/origin.html"),
        )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator_enum(MYADDON_OT_operator.bl_idname, "options")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYADDON_OT_operator)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.prepend(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[Further reading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275041/adding-an-operator-to-the-context-menu-of-a-uilist/275555#275555)

Comment: This method works well, it's not super comfortable, but it does the job I expected! This is really helpful, I didn't know the "button_operator" attribute, is really helpful.

Comment: Hehe agreed. It's ugly but AFAIK the prettiest way to query for this information :) There is also `button_prop` and `button_pointer` FWIW. See the docs in my link